# How to add a listener with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a page in Chrome and I want it to show a modal when the user clicks an image but when I try it with my localhost it does nothing. I think there's a problema with a listener. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  document.getElementByClass(".call-to-action").addEventListener("click", openModal());

});

function openModal() {
  $("html").addClass("modal-open");
}
```

My CSS:

```
.modal-open
  .modal
    opacity: 1
    pointer-events: all
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: it is `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: No, I'm not using jQuery

Comment: The how are you getting `.addClass` and `$(document).ready(function() {` to work?

Comment: @kukkuz I've already tried `getElementsByClassName` but it doesn't work

Comment: @j08691 just using js, sorry if it is a non-sense, I'm new coding with js

Comment: Some of your code requires [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) which is a javascript library to run.   You can see examples on how to include it in your project [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp).   [This](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp) will show you how to use JQuery events and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) will show you how to use pure javascript.  Click the "Try it Yourself" link to see the full html/javascript for the examples

Answer (score 2):

This might help you, cheers!

If you are using **Jquery**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".call-to-action").on("click", openModal);

});

function openModal() {
  $("html").addClass("modal-open");
}
```

```css
html.modal-open{
  
  background: #ddd;
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <input class="call-to-action" type="button" value="CTA"/>
  </body>
```

If you are using **javascript**:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("call-to-action")[0].addEventListener("click", openModal);



function openModal() {
  document.documentElement.classList.add("modal-open");
}
```

```css
html.modal-open {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input class="call-to-action" type="button" value="CTA" />
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, I've already tried both but none of them work. Thanks tho :(

Comment: Okok, please give me a day and I'll let you know how it goes, thanks!

Comment: This will work. Make sure you include jquery if you are using jquery.